# How does AsQueryable() work internally?

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb, asqueryable

Maybe it's simple question, but does `AsQueryable()` have some performance loss?

Generally speaking we are working with RavenDB and we have existing code like this

```
protected override IQueryable<T> QueryableIndexRawQuery(string rawQuery, int skip = 0, int take = 128, string indexName = null) 
{ 
    var defaultIndexName = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(indexName) ? indexName : string.Format("{0}{1}", typeof(T).Name, IndexPreffix);

    return this.Session.Advanced.DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.GetIndex(defaultIndexName) != null 
        ? this.Session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<T>(defaultIndexName).Statistics(out this.Statistics).Skip(skip).Take(take).Where(rawQuery).AsQueryable()
        : this.Session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<T>().Statistics(out this.Statistics).Skip(skip).Take(take).Where(rawQuery).AsQueryable();
}
```

So Where clause return us `IDocumentQuery` then we try to represent it `AsQueryable()`

```
this.Session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<T>(defaultIndexName).Statistics(out this.Statistics).Skip(skip).Take(take).Where(rawQuery)
```

The question what `AsQueryable()` eventually does internally? How does it convert it?
Answers with in-memory collection examples like `List<>` will be really useful as well.

Like this:

```
    var list = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
    list.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: This is complicated, but it's [explained somewhat by Jon Skeet on this page](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/20/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-43-out-of-process-queries-with-iqueryable.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`.AsQueryable()` forces us to evaluate the query in memory, since you are using `session.Advanced.LuceneQuery()`. This is NOT recommended.
You need to use `session.Query()` if you want to use IQueryable.

Comment: Ok, we are LuceneQuery because we need to server side filtering, which is pretty completecated. For example, how can we do such filtering with session.Query() - var query = _session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Entity>().Where("(Name:(*ontra*)) AND (LabelKey:(*ontra*)) OR (DescriptionKey:(*ontra*) AND (LabelKey: (*tra*)))").ToList(); We can use Search() method, but it is not suitable for composite conditions. Maybe it is another question, but the initial one was raised by it.